# ng-repeat with form in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-forms

I have created dynamic forms with ng-repeat directive. I am getting form field according to userid value. Once I have filled every field in form my add user button should be enabled. As of now its not enabled. I have attached my code below.

**My html code:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form role="form" name='userForm' novalidate>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" ng-repeat="myid in userid">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label>ID</label>
                        <input ng-model="myid" id="myid" name="myid" placeholder="Enter bugid" type="text" required readonly disabled>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label>Comments</label>
                        <textarea ng-model="manualComment" id="textarea1" rows="1"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3 ">
                        <label>Gender</label>

                        <select ng-model="gender" name="select2">
                            <option value="male">Male</option>
                            <option value="female">Female</option>

                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="buttonContainer text-center btn-container">
            <br>
            <button ng-disabled="!(myid  && manualComment && gender)" type="button" id="adduser">Add user</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn button--default btn--small pull-center">Close</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

my app.js file

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.userid = [1, 2, 3]
});
```

How can I enable add user button once all field are filled?

Comment: you might need `ng-disabled`

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

If you want to convert your initial array from the server to a usage array check this fiddle

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

If you want an object which contains all the form values, please refer to the below fiddle!

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Based on the statement below, this is my solution.

> How can I enable add user button once all field are filled?

I have added the `required` attribute to all the input fields, the form name `userForm` is a variable in the scope. It has its validation variables, in my case I am using `userForm.$invalid` which will be true unless all the fields with `required` attribute are filled. The `Add User` is disabled by using the `ng-disabled` attribute, check the below JSFiddle for a demo.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

```
<div ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form role="form" name='userForm' novalidate>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" ng-repeat="myid in userid">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label>ID</label>
                        <input ng-model="myid" id="myid" name="myid" placeholder="Enter bugid" type="text" required readonly disabled>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label>Comments</label>
                        <textarea ng-model="manualComment" id="textarea1" rows="1" required></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3 ">
                        <label>Gender</label>

                        <select ng-model="gender" name="select2" required>
                            <option value="male">Male</option>
                            <option value="female">Female</option>

                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="buttonContainer text-center btn-container">
            <br>
            <button ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid" type="button" id="adduser">Add user</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn button--default btn--small pull-center">Close</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: how can i get each field model value in this example . i need to pass this model value to server.

Comment: @user3760261 Updated my answer!

Comment: According to my requirement  my  $scope.userid has only userid's .  in that i cant attach any value like you did. is there any other way to get this model values

Comment: @user3760261 Generate this object with the `$scope.userid`, its a simple for loop, you didn't mention this in the question :(

Comment: once i am connect with my server this $scope.userid get more than 100 userid  . how can i attach this object to that $scope.userid. can you please send sample fiddle for this

Comment: @user3760261 Was this answer helpful?